# Multiple static function call method

Tags: php, class

When I using `static::find()` function, i want to return the db row result. But at another case, I would like to link to a new class static function `update()`. For example `static::find(1)->update()` and this case `return new static` needed. I could't find out a condition to decide which return method required. Good day.

```
class A {
    public static function find($id){

        global $db_link;

        $id = (integer)$id;

        if($id){

            $stmt = $db_link->prepare("select * from ".static::get_table_name()." where ".static::$primary_key." = :id limit 1");
            $stmt->execute([":id" => $id]);
            $return = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(!empty($return)){

                static::$primary_id[] = $return["id"];
                static::$data = $return;

            }

        }

        return new static;

        return static::format_success($return);

    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking.

Comment: `static::find()` return a result array, `static::find()->update()` to run a function using that result. But once I using `return new static`, `static::find()` does not have any output.

Comment: A function call in PHP has no idea what you're about to do with the result - `find` can't return an array in one case and an object in another. Also, `return new static` returns a new instance of the class in which it's running. I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: `return new static` needed for `static::find()->update()`. But i want `static::find()` functional too to display db result.

Comment: `find()` should, if it is successful, return an array, and you cannot call a method of an array. Please don't call classes 'static' and variables 'return', these are keywords in PHP and create a lot of confusion.

Comment: `return new static` will return a static object if `static::find()->update()` being called, and i wish to call the next method class function.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing with the `update` case now. But again, *a function call in PHP has no idea what you're about to do with the result*. There's no condition you can check to see what the calling code is going to do next, and even if there was it would completely break the idea of encapsulation.

Comment: I see, but eloquent able to do that. I have checked how they doing this, and i have no idea the condition they coded based on my knowledge level. Btw thanks for help :)

Comment: In Eloquent's case, the return type is always an object. It just happens to be an object that implements [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php), so it will behave like an array in certain situations (e.g. when you're getting/setting values).